# Adding Python package to path for VSCode terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, doctest

I'm writing python classes in a package using VScode. I want to add this package's parent directory to the Python path when using the VScode Terminal so I can `import` the package (regardless of the directory of the file that's being run).

I've tried a `.env` file and Workspace settings without success.

Ultimately I want to run doctests on the classes using the terminal, and for that the terminal needs to be able import the package.

### .env File

I have a Workspace. I first tried adding a `.env` file as follows (note I'm using Python 3 Anaconda on **Windows**):

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\\MyPython;${PYTHONPATH}
```

(I've tried single & double back slashes and forward slashes, nothing works).

When I run a script (`test.py`) in the terminal containing this:

```
print(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))
```

I just get back `None`.

I did try setting a system wide PYTHONPATH environment variable in Windows, which then shows up, but the C:\MyPython is not added to it. I don't want to have to add/change the system PYTHONPATH every time I open a different Workspace!

### Workspace Settings

I then tried adding Workspace settings in the **`MyProject.code-workspace`** file:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "C:\\MyPython"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.cwd": "C:\\MyPython",
        "terminal.integrated.env.windows": "C:\\MyPython"
    }
}
```

Again this didn't work.

### File Structure

My file structure is as follows:

```
C:\MyPython
    .env
    MyProject.code-workspace
    test.py
    Pkg\
        __init__.py
        Class1.py
        Class2.py
```

If I use the green triangle button ("Run File in Python Terminal") to run `test.py` then that file's directory (`C:\MyPython`) gets added to `sys.path` and everything works (e.g. `import Pkg.Class1` works).

However if I run `Class2.py` (which includes `import Pkg.Class1` in the code and doctest) then instead the directory `C:\MyPython\Pkg` gets added to `sys.path` and it can't find and import the `Pkg` package and the `doctest` fails.

As such I want to add `C:\MyPython` to the python path, regardless of the directory of the file that is being run.

Of course, I could just add all tests to `test.py` and run that, but I really just want to run the doctests in the class I'm working on, rather than have to run all the tests every time (and flip to another file to do it).

It seems like this should be easy, but I can't get it to work!

Any ideas?

PS: I haven't included the .py code for the test or classes since it's irrelevant to the problem, it's the `import` that fails. Ultimately I can see that the required directory appears neither in `sys.path` nor in `os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH')` and that's why the import fails.

Answer (score 0):

So two things. One, Python is not designed for you to execute files contained within packages, so you're somewhat going against its design trying to make this work. It would be better to do something like use Python's `-m` flag to do what you want, e.g. `python -m Pkg.Class2`. That way you don't have to manipulate your paths to run a module contained in your package.

Two, you were very close in getting what you were after with your settings, but you accidentally used a string instead of an object for specifying your environment variables for your terminal. What you wanted was:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {"PYTHONPATH": "C:\\MyPython"}
```